# Installing windows 8 on XPS 13 developer edition

Tags: xps

i am considering buying the XPS 13 developer edition, but i need a program a program there is only available on windows. So i wanna hear if anyone knows if it's possbile to install windows along side ubuntu on it, now when it comes pre isntalled with ubuntu?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

If you have a copy of Windows, it is possible to install it.
Although, if you do not or simply want better integration, use [WINE](http://www.winehq.org/).
Or, if you want to run Windows inside Ubuntu and have a copy of Windows, you can install it inside [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/). This will basically have the same effect as installing Windows alongside Ubuntu.

Comment: yes i know but when i had a computer ( was send to repair but it coulnd't be done) i think i not was possible to do with the program i need. does is it work with all programs? is there a site to see which?

Comment: Sure. http://appdb.winehq.org/

Comment: okay thanks. What about the virtuel option, will i be able to run a full screen windows version through a virtuel machine?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my post to reflect that.